# Unable to drag (re-order) layers within Table of Contents in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, table-of-contents

I added Raster data from a folder into ArcMap 10.1 and I cannot seem to drag any layer within the Table of Contents.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 22):

On the Table of Contents pane just below the words "Table of Contents" there should be 5 buttons.

Ensure that you are on the first button called "List by Drawing Order".

This mode allows you to do the dragging that you want.

A trap for new users is that adding a table to ArcMap changes the Table of Contents to List By Source View (because that is the only View Type that lists tables), which they often do not notice, causing them to "lose" the ability to re-order layers.

Comment: Odd case here, in windows-8, one arcmap window is opened as admin and another as regular user. Then I can't drag from TOC of Regular User to TOC of Admin but reverse works fine.

Comment: I think that's by design. Does that work on windows 7?

Comment: Having the same problem, but the suggested solution does not solve the problem

Comment: @Peter M Macharia  my order was locked despite "List by Drawing Order". In my case caused by another crashed MXD.